# Displaying web user controls in a grid with paging

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, paging

I have written a user control and I want to display its instances in a grid (like a NxM cells table) and with paging. Which control should I use and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

A [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) or [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) should be able to meet your requirements.